# Rake task sending email newsletters failing when using Heroku Scheduler addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, scheduler, sendgrid

I have a rake task set up to fire once per day on a Rails app. It checks which users need a newsletter sent, then prepares the newsletter and sends it using SendGrid starter-level addon via DelayedJob queue.

When I run this rake job from the command line with `heroku run rake my_job` it works, and the newsletters get sent out. When I leave it to the Heroku Scheduler addon to run, the newsletters don't get sent. The script runs ok (I add the details of each newsletter sent to a table), but the emails are not sent, and do not remain in the DelayedJob queue when I check it out.

How can I go about debugging this? The scheduled job uses exact same `rake my_job` syntax. I am running 1 web dyno and 1 worker dyno 24/7.